# How to install ACL on Samsung tizen smart tv for running android apps?

Tags: android, acl, tizen, television, samsung

Does anyone know how to install this [ https://androzentpkstore.blogspot.com/2019/01/original-acl-for-tizen.html ] (ACL for tizen) on Samsung Tizen smart tv ?

I tried uploading the tpk app on the tv by using these instructions [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308306/how-to-install-apps-on-samsung-tizen-tv-from-command-line ] but while it uploads correctly the tv blocks the app and wont allow the install there is no "allow from unknown sources" on my tv after latest firmware upgrade, developer mode is on

anyone made it somehow to run android apps on tizen tv ? That's what I'm trying to do anyways I don't know if there is any way other than installing ACL

thanks